# Unable to access index of tabBar item using swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uitabbaritem

Environment: xcode 6GM, Language Swift.
I was setting image color of a tabBar item using this code in xcode 6 beta2

```
var cameraTab : UITabBarItem = self.tabBar.items[1] as UITabBarItem
```

But now in xcode 6GM it is giving error. 
Error: [AnyObject]? does not have a member named 'subscript'

Comment: Either `tabBar` or `items` are Optional.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

items is Optional - you can do:

```
   if let items = self.tabBar.items {
    println("\(items[1])")
  }
```

or

```
  var cameraTab : UITabBarItem = self.tabBar.items![1] as UITabBarItem
```

Comment: Thanks! Great simple answer!

Answer (score 1):

`items` property is optional for `tabBar`. Try optional chaining:

```
var cameraTab : UITabBarItem = self.tabBar.items?[1] as UITabBarItem
```