# change storyboard tab bar icon using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I've created a tab bar controller and embedded several view controllers in it. I then try to set a specific tab bar item in a corresponding swift file for that view. Problem is that I am changing the item by overriding the "viewDidLoad" function. So it only updates after the user has touched that item. What be a better approach to changing storyboard tab bar items using swift?

Comment: I got it using the following answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25868869/3498764

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a subclass of UITabBarController
2. set this custom class of your TabBarController
3. now you override UITabBarController ViewDidLoad Method
4. there you can access all the TabItems and change their text/images
   before a ViewController get loaded.

   ```
      class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let allItems:[AnyObject] = self.tabBar.items!
       var item1:UITabBarItem = allItems[0] as! UITabBarItem
       var item2:UITabBarItem = allItems[1] as! UITabBarItem


       item1.image = UIImage(named: "menu@2x.png")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
       item2.image = UIImage(named: "play@2x.png")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
   }
   ```

   }

in custom class the code should be like as above... 
you can set selectedState Image as well....

here is the result..

[image]